# How to compile libogg and libvorbis for Android

Tags: android-ndk, ndk-build

In my Android app, I would like to implement the libogg and libvorbis libraries, so I can play and manipulate ogg files.

Unfortunately, I haven't managed to find any tutorial that can explain how to achieve that.

That said, here is what I found the most interesting: https://github.com/inetic/ogg-vorbis-for-android

But I don't really understand how to use it to compile the libraries for the following ABIs:

- armeabi-v7a
- arm64-v8a
- x86
- x86_64

Can someone explain me how to compile those libraries for Android?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

I finally managed to make it work, and also managed to implement the libraries in an Android project.

I created a simple Github project with a detailed explanation here: https://github.com/mregnauld/ogg-vorbis-libraries-android